# Long time between repaints

Tags: java, timer, jpanel, paint, jlabel

I'm creating a menu with two moving objects. The code is as below :

```
public void drawPageZero()
{
    repaint.setData(repaint0.getData());
    Graphics g = repaint.createGraphics();
    if (xN < - napisBar.getWidth())
    {
        xN = 2 * napisBar.getWidth();
    }
    if (xN < 0 && xN >= -napisBar.getWidth())
    {
        xN2 = xN + napisBar.getWidth();
        xN3 = xN + 2 *napisBar.getWidth();
    }
    else if (xN <= 2*napisBar.getWidth() && xN >= napisBar.getWidth())
    {
        xN2 = xN - 2*napisBar.getWidth();
        xN3 = xN - napisBar.getWidth();
    }
    else if (xN >= 0 && xN < napisBar.getWidth())
    {
        xN2 = xN + napisBar.getWidth();
        xN3 = xN - napisBar.getWidth();
    }
    g.drawImage(napisBar,xN,0,this);
    g.drawImage(napisBar,xN2,0,this);
    g.drawImage(napisBar,xN3,0,this);
    if (xW < - walutyBar.getWidth())
    {
        xW = 2 * walutyBar.getWidth();
    }
    if (xW < 0 && xW >= -walutyBar.getWidth())
    {
        xW2 = xW + walutyBar.getWidth();
        xW3 = xW + 2 *walutyBar.getWidth();
    }
    else if (xW <= 2*walutyBar.getWidth() && xW >= walutyBar.getWidth())
    {
        xW2 = xW - 2*walutyBar.getWidth();
        xW3 = xW - walutyBar.getWidth();
    }
    else if (xW >= 0 && xW < walutyBar.getWidth())
    {
        xW2 = xW + walutyBar.getWidth();
        xW3 = xW - walutyBar.getWidth();
    }
    g.drawImage(walutyBar,xW,400,this);
    g.drawImage(walutyBar,xW2,400,this);
    g.drawImage(walutyBar,xW3,400,this);
    image = new ImageIcon(repaint.getScaledInstance(sizeX,sizeY, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    imageLabel.setIcon(image);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new infoBar(), 1);
}
```

And the timer :

```
class infoBar extends TimerTask
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (page ==0) {
            xN -= 1;
            xW -= 1;
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            drawPageZero();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }

    }
}
```

Both "walutyBar" and "infoBar" are created at the startup of the program. I need to reload background each time due to overwriting it with pictures (thats why setData is used). I've set 1 ms to the Timer, yet objects are moving much slowly. Which of the processes uses most CPU time and is there any easy way to shorten it ? (aka. make drawPageZero function to complete faster). Thanks in advance for Your help ! :)

Comment: Don’t use `java.util.Timer` to manipulate the UI ! Use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading

Comment: Changed util.Timer to swing.Timer, but it didn't help at all with the problem. Maybe there is other way to display such screen ?

Comment: Avoid calling `getScaledInstance` again and again. Instead, create the scaled instance only **once** and re-use it. But from quickly skimming over the code, it seems that there is a **serious** issue: It seems like you are creating a timer that *starts a new timer every millisecond* (and each timer started there starts new timers every millisecond, causing an avalance of timers!) - but maybe I misunderstood something here...

Comment: Yeah, I create timer each time, but I discard it after triggering it. If many timers would run at once, then the display should run in chaos, while it is stable. I'll try with commenting out getScaledInstance.

Comment: Thanks, seems like getScaledInstance took a lot of CPU time. Now it works faster & smoothly. Is there maybe any faster way than setData for BufferedImaged ?